# Chrome omnibox behavior

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

In my corporate network, to access an intranet site like "ABC.COMPANY.COM", we just type "ABC" in the firefox/IE address bar and press enter. Since we are inside the "COMPANY.COM" domain, the browser takes us to "ABC.COMPANY.COM".

But the behavior of Chrome omnibox is sort of annoying. It Google searches for "ABC" rather than taking us to the site. Any tips to go to "ABC.COMPANY.COM" instead without typing the whole address?

Thanks.

Comment: type in the full address few times & Omnibox will learn it and autocomplete it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Say your company's site URL is extremely awkward or messy. 
Assume the TLD is

```
longurl.com
```

But, the actual intranet site is located at the following URL:

```
https://abc.longurl.com/intranet_homer.aspx/?q="node_5"
```

---

In Chrome's address bar/Omnibox, enter:

> `chrome://settings/searchEngines`

This should bring up a list of search engines and their query strings. At the bottom of the list should be three blank input boxes for adding a custom search engine.

They are for:

1. search engine title (1)
2. earch engine base URL (2), the latter of which is actually an alias for
3. the full search query URL string (3).

Now, enter:

1. *Any name/title you want* - it's trivial.
2. Your preferred **keyword** - `abc`, say.
3. The full URL

Click *Done* to save it. And there's your custom keyword ready to go.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but my answer works - if it's not what you were looking for - e.g. if you want to view __files__, then the question wasn't clear on that. What OS environment? In windows files would be accessed with `file:///X:/path/to/file.ext/` where `X` is the shared network drive. But that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

Ps: you can then _still_ map that as I explained as a search query of your choice.

Comment: Another thing: in _Windows_, the server location as the other person answered would use backslashes ie. `\\abc\` or `\\server_front_office\` - specificity required.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `//abc/`

This indicates to the browser not to do a search. You will instead browse to machine name abc, which your network likely redirects to abc.domain.com.

If you type abc and Chrome runs a search for the term, there should be a bubble that appears prompting if you meant `http://abc/` instead of a search. If you say yes, Chrome will remember this setting for you.